# grep command in an if statement

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter search term here: " searchT

if [[ $(cat test.txt | grep -wi '$searchT') ]]; then     
    echo "$(cat test.txt | grep '$searchT' && wc -l) number of matches found"
    echo $(cat test.txt | grep '$searchT')

else echo "no match found"    

fi

exit 0
```

How do I make the script run if the `if statement` is true. when i run the script the script will output the `else` statement. because there is no value to compare with the grep command.

Comment: The variable `$searchT` will not expand inside single quotes. Use double quotes instead: `"$searchT"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way to cache the results: [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) consumes its stdin into an array, each line is an array element.

```sh
mapfile -t results < <(grep -wi "$searchT" test.txt)
num=${#results[@]}

if ((num == 0)); then
    echo "no match found"
else
    echo "found $num matches"
    printf "%s\n" "${results[@]}"
fi
```

Answer (score 11):

It's not precisely clear what you are trying to match, but remember that `if` takes a command and evaluates its returns value.  `grep`  succeeds if it matches, and fails if it does not.  So you probably just want to do:

```
if grep -q -wi "$searchT" test.txt; then
   ...
fi
```

Note that you should use double quotes so that "$searchT" is expanded and its value is passed as the argument to grep, and there is no need for `cat`.

In your original code, you have the line `echo $(cat test.txt | grep '$searchT')`, which has several issues, but I will just address the anti-pattern `echo $(cmd)`.  The `$()` gathers the output of `cmd` and passes it as arguments to `echo`, which then writes them. Instead of `echo $(cmd)`, you can almost always just do `cmd` and cut out the middle man.  (`echo` will squeeze whitespace and perhaps treat some of the output of `cmd` as flags, so the output is not always identical, but it is almost always what you want.  If you are actually using `echo $(cmd)` intentionally to squash whitespace or are using flags in the output of `cmd`, you have a code readability issue!)  In this case, there is an easier solution than using `echo` here, though.  Just omit the `-q` from the `grep` command and let the output be written.

Comment: it still gives me no match

Comment: i even tried using the `$(cat test.txt | grep '$searchT' && wc -l)` in the if statement so that if the output was `-ge` than 1 then echo the commands.

Comment: You need to use double quotes.  You are searching for the literal string `$searchT` instead of the entered string.

Comment: Also, `grep "$searchT" && wc -l` is not going to send the output of `grep` to wc.  Instead, if there are any matches, `wc -l` will read from its stdin, which (if you are running interactively) means that it will block waiting for you to type something into your tty.

Comment: using grep something && wc -l has no sense. grep supports -c option, that counts how manay string is found. wc -l have some problem, it counts new line characters, not number of lines. new line char at the end of last line, is not mandatory. then it won't be counted. grep -c ^ repairs this problem, it count start of each line.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $((n=$(grep -wic "$searchT" test.txt))) -ge 0 ]; then
    echo "found ${n}"
else
    echo "not found ${n}"
fi
```

modified based on comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

if n=$(grep -wic "$searchT" test.txt); then
    echo "found ${n}"
else
    echo "not found ${n}"
fi
```

Comment: This works, but is a terrible anti-pattern.  This is not the right thing to do.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, care to elaborate?

Comment: Just `if n=$(grep -wic "$searchT" test.txt); then` why the `[` and `ge` comparison.

Comment: Ack!  `if n=$( grep ..)` is even worse!  That does not check if `n` is zero, it checks the status of the `grep` so you might as well just do `if grep ...` and stop confusing the reader!

Comment: @vgersh99 It is not the right thing to do because it is excessively confusing and perpetuates the horrible notion that `if` requires its command to be `[` or `[[`.  The grammar of `if` is simple; `if command; then ....`.  So just write `if grep ...` instead of storing a count of lines and doing the unnecessary extra work.  Computers are only as efficient as the commands they are given, and storing the count just to compare it to zero is extra, unnecessary work.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the OP wanted to output the number of matches in the ```then``` block of the ```if```` . Hence, the assignment in the ```if``` - 2 birds with 1 stone. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: If you want to retain some data from grep, then the `if n=$(grep...` is reasonable.